# C# Class How to increment speed on form?

Tags: c#

I'm having, what I hope, is a small issue with my code. The "Current Speed" is supposed to increase by 5 every time I hit the "Accelerate" button and go down by 5 when I hit the "Brake" button. Currently, when I hit "Accelerate it shows I'm going 5, but will not increase past that. When I hit "Brake" it just shows -5. I feel like I've been staring at this for a few hours now and I feel like it's probably something simple I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Form Image]

Here is my form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CarClass
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Car myCar;

        public Form1()
        {
            myCar = new Car();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetCarData()
        {
            try
            {
                myCar.Make = carMakeText.Text;
                myCar.Year = int.Parse(carYearText.Text);
                myCar.Speed = 0;
            }
            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void accButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.AccSpeed(5);
            enteredMakeLabel.Text = myCar.Make;
            enteredYearLabel.Text = myCar.Year.ToString();
            currentSpeedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();
        }

        private void brakeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.DecSpeed(5);
            enteredMakeLabel.Text = myCar.Make;
            enteredYearLabel.Text = myCar.Year.ToString();
            currentSpeedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CarClass
{
    class Car
    {
        private int year;
        private string make;
        private int speed;

        public Car()
        {
            this.year = 1994;
            this.make = "Ford";
            this.speed = 0;
        }

        public Car(string make, int year, int speed)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.make = make;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return make; }
            set { make = value; }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return year; }
            set { year = value; }
        }

        public int Speed
        {
            get { return speed; }
            set { speed = value; }
        }

        public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
        {
            
            speed += speedIncrement;
        }

        public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
        {

            speed -= speedDecrement;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in GetCarData(); you set the speed back to 0. If you remove that line the code will do what you expect.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot for not catching that. Thank you so much!